# conditions for existence of orthogonal function expansion

Tags: functional-analysis

Do the Dirichlet conditions for Fourier series apply to orthogonal functions generally (with perhaps an appropriate weight function) over an interval [a,b]?  What about Laguerre and Hermite, which are defined over an infinite interval?

Comment: What do you mean by Dirichlet conditions? What type of conditions are referring to?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions

Comment: Then, yes, Dirichlet conditions will give convergence of the orthogonal expansions. On the infinite interval, you need some condition of integrability or square integrability. Classical proofs of this are not easy for the Hermite case, but the result holds.

Comment: A condition of integrability is required even for Fourier. On an infinite interval, then, I would expect absolute integrability of a function multiplied by the square-root of the weight function to be required.

Comment: @gilonik : The Dirichlet condition require local integrability in order to make sense. A global condition such as $L^1$ is also needed. The global condition just needs to be good enough to argue the Riemann-Lebesgue type of lemma to force vanishing of the tail integrals in the limit.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts:  Thank you!

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: "A global condition such as $L^1$
 is also needed."  I presume $L^2$ is sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  I seem to recall that $L^1$ was a little more convenient for a singular problem on an infinite interval.